# A few questions about Bartle's formulation of the Archimedean Property of $\mathbf{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

There are a few things about Bartle's formulation of Archimedes' Axiom in his book Elements of Real Analysis that I don't understand. Let me first formulate Archimedes' Axiom in the way I'm used to, which follows from the Completeness Property of $\mathbf{R}$:

> Given $x \in \mathbf{R}$ and $k \in \mathbf{Z}^{+}$, there is a unique
> $m \in \mathbf{Z}$ such that $(m-1)k \leq x < mk$.

Here's Bartle's formulation of the Archimedean Property:

[image]

What I don't understand is his insistence on everything being positive. What is gained from having this restriction? Since everything must be greater than $0$, the proofs of various theorems that rely on it must branch out into cases. This leads me to my next question, about his proof of $\mathbf{Q}$ being dense in $\mathbf{R}$:

[image]

As you can see, his way of introducing Archimedes' Axiom forces the proof to involve separate cases ($y>0$, $y \leq 0$). Furthermore, I fail to see why the inequality highlighted in $\color{red}{\textrm{red}}$ is needed. It's not used in the proof at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the completeness of ${\mathbb R}$ in order to "prove" the Archimedean axiom is cheating, because the Archimedean property is already present in ${\mathbb N}$ and should be proven from the Peano axioms. Why should you need completeness, established to prove the existence of numbers like $\sqrt{2}$, $e$, or $\pi$, to prove the existence of a natural number? Completeness (be it in terms of order or in terms of Cauchy sequences) is a statement about the *fine structure* of ${\mathbb R}$ (and derived spaces), whereas the Archimedean principle deals with the global "Gestalt" (morphology) of the number system.

In Theorem 5.13 Bartle works with positive real numbers because the natural numbers are positive and handy to work with! Of course one then has to perform a small detour to extend the relevant statements to all of ${\mathbb R}$, but this is peanuts.

Comment: Finally I find one person on MSE who has similar opinion about using completeness to prove Archimedean property. +1

Comment: I can see how one proves the Archimedean axiom for $\mathbf{N}$, and the extension to $\mathbf{Q}$, but isn't the usual Archimedean axiom a statement about the deep relationship between the unboundedness of $\mathbf{N}$, and the completeness of $\mathbf{R}$? I don't quite see how one shows this without using appealing to the fact that a nonempty subset of reals bounded above has a $\operatorname{sup}$. Please do spell this out, or link to a previous answer of yours that spelled it out.

Comment: I have read your edit to this answer, but I still respectfully request that you produce a proof of Archimedes' axiom from the Peano axioms (just for $\mathbf{R}$, I can see how to do it for $\mathbf{N}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$). All the books I've read do it using completeness, and I haven't seen a single one which does it using the Peano axioms, so I think your answer would be a nice contribution to the lack of this particular viewpoint in the literature.

Comment: If you believe the Archimedean axiom for ${\mathbb Q}$ you are done, since by construction (say, with Dedekind cuts) any real number $\alpha$ can be enclosed between two rationals, hence is smaller than some $n\in{\mathbb N}$.

Comment: Right, but an approach which merely gives $\mathbf{R}$ as a complete ordered field, without constructing it, must still use $\operatorname{sup}$.